# document.getElementById on rendered angular content not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Appreciate all the help I can get as I am still new to angular. One of the issues that I am trying to solve is to scroll the user to an element in the page after the angular view which is getting its content from an external source has finished loading.

Looking through the documentation it seems that `angular.element(document).ready` is not going to work since the document may be ready but the inline content that I am fetching using `$http.get` may not rendered yet.

So I looked into using `$q` and promises and so far I have this in my controller (stripping out some stuff for brevity):

```
.controller('myController', function($scope, $http, $q) {
  var promises = [];
  var data = ["/json/my-feed-url"];

  // kind of unnecessary but copying boilerplate code...
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    promises.push($http.get(d))
  });

  // wait for json to be loaded
  $q.all(promises).then(function(results){
    results.forEach(function(data,status,headers,config){
      console.log(data,status,headers,config);
      $scope.document_data_inline = data.data.nodes;
    })
  // now once all the data has been read into the document
  // find a tag and scroll to it
  }).then(function() {
    var p = window.location.hash;
    var t = document.getElementById(p);
    console.dir(t);
    // here is where t is always undefined
    // yet I am rendering that element inline through my json
    // which (presumably) since we are chaining this function with 'then'
    // should be rendered at this point as all promises have completed...
    ...
```

Kind of stumped since I thought I was doing this logically. My json feed includes special anchor tags that serve as reference points for inline scrolling, yet the line where i call `document.getElementById` always returns `undefined` even though I can verify that the document is present. Of course I can run this `document.getElementById` code from the console and it works every time as at that point the document body is assembled, but I thought that also happens after the promises have finished loading...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks
- J

Comment: Couldn´t you scroll to an conataining id? Like: `<div id="wrapper"> ... place where fetched content will be loaded </div>`

Comment: You need to look into the $digest cycle. Although you've set the $scope variable, the actual binding to the HTML is not happening until the next $digest cycle. You'll want to use something like `$timeout` or `$scope.$evalAsync`.

Comment: @mike-mccaughan - thanks! will look into that